# Escaping basename in bourne shell when using find

Tags: shell, find

I want to merge output of three logwatch outputs and pipe result through sendmail.

Example:

```
#!/bin/sh
LOG_DIR="/var/log/remote-hosts"
MAIL_TO="me@email.com"

sh -c "logwatch && find ${LOG_DIR} -type d -name \"ip*\" -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} sh -c 'logwatch --logdir {} --hostname $(basename {})'" | 
sed '1!b;s/^/To: '${MAIL_TO}'\nSubject: Logwatch report\n\n/' | sendmail -t
```

first logwatch is executed on /var/log folder
and then I would like to traverse /var/log/remote-hosts subfolders (ip-10-0-0-38 and ip-10-0-0-39 ) with find and also do logwatch on them.

The merged output will be sent throught sentmail. However I would like to replace hostname with basename of /var/log/remote-hosts subfolder so instead of /var/log/remote-hosts/ip-10-0-0-38 I will have ip-10-0-0-38 only.

But unfortunatelly I don't how to do the basename part correctly. Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using `sh -c`? The extra level of quoting makes this more difficult than it needs to be.

Comment: The problem is that `$(basename {})` is being substituted into the string BEFORE `find`, because of the outer `sh -`.

Comment: first sh -c is for merging outputs of all logwatch before they're piped to sendmail. My point is to "compile" one report for all my servers. I have central log server, which collects all logs using rsyslogd and I would like to schedule cron job, which will send me one email with reports for all my servers.

Comment: Why not just do `(logwatch && ...) | sed ...` to merge the outputs?

Comment: @Barmar thanks a lot. I've replaced first `sh -c` with parentheses as you suggested. And it works now. But I'm still curious, can it be done with `sh -c` as in my original version? Or it's imposible?

Comment: Yeah, you can probably do it with `\$(basename {})`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `sh -c` for grouping statements, use `(...)`:

```
(logwatch && find ${LOG_DIR} -type d -name "ip*" -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} sh -c 'logwatch --logdir {} --hostname $(basename {})') |
    sed '1!b;s/^/To: '${MAIL_TO}'\nSubject: Logwatch report\n\n/' | sendmail -t
```